# How do I create a new AnyType array

Tags: java, arrays

I am using the code from the answer [How do I create a new AnyType[] array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664594/how-do-i-create-a-new-anytype-array) . My question is how to initialize this array. When I try to run this code, I get a null pointer exception on Clear(), which I think is due to using theItems.getClass since theItems haven't been declared already.

```
public class Whatever<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>>  extends AbstractCollection<AnyType> implements List<AnyType> {

private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
private static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

private AnyType[] theItems;
private int theSize;
private int modCount = 0;


public Whatever() {
    clear();
}

/**
 * Change the size of this collection to zero.
 */
public void clear() {
    theSize = 0;
    theItems = (AnyType[]) java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(theItems.getClass().getComponentType(), DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
    modCount++;
}
}
```

Comment: "which I think is due to..." - why don't you debug it and find out if you're correct with that assumption?

Comment: you are right about the exception. you need an already created array for that to work. Or have the Class object for the component type handy already.

Comment: i found this: http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/instantiating-generic-arrays/28693/view.html . Might interest you

Comment: You seem to want to implement the equivalent of an ArrayList: a list backed by an array. If you look at the source code of ArrayList, what's the type of the array? It's `Object[]`.

Comment: You're trying to use `theItems` as part of its own initialization.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found two ways I could accomplish this. The first, using Jack's comment from above, looks like:

```
public static <T> T[] alloc(int length, T ... base) {
    return Arrays.copyOf( base, length );
}
```

It can then be called like:

```
theItems = ClassName.alloc(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
```

The way I ended up using could be used because I implemented comparable:

```
theItems = (AnyType []) new Comparable[ DEFAULT_CAPACITY ];
```